# Update a JPopupMenu menu items while it is open

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu

In my UI i have a JPopMenu with values as ,

for e.g A,B,C

[image]

The scenario is,

1. I opened the JPopupMenu and kept it open.
2. At back end with a timer running , it updates the content B to some other alphabet at frequent interval.

   3.I want the JPopupMenu to get updated while it is kept open.

In current behavior if i close and open JPopupMenu the updated value shows up.

I tried `repaint()`but it doesn't do anything.

What is the best way to do this?? Am new to swings please help.

Comment: Please post some code about what you have tried so far. It's hard to help you without.

Comment: Programatically close and open the popup once you have done with your updation.

Answer (score 1):

Menu items can change their content at run time just fine. Without seeing your code it's hard to tell what you're doing wrong, but here's a working example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener;

public class PopupTest {
    private static final String[] messages = {
        "You are today's 1000th user!",
        "You have won an internet!",
        "Claim your prize!"
    };

    private PopupTest() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("You have won");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Check your prize!");
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.add(lbl);
        frame.pack();

        final JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
        final JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(messages[0]);
        menu.add(item);
        menu.add(new JMenuItem("Another item that does not work"));

        final Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            int count;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                count++;
                count %= messages.length;
                item.setText(messages[count]);
            }
        });

        menu.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener() {
            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                timer.stop();
            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                timer.stop();
            }
        });

        lbl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                maybeShowPopup(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                maybeShowPopup(e);
            }

            private void maybeShowPopup(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    menu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                    timer.start();
                }
            }
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new PopupTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .revalidate() with .repaint() it might help.
  [The docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate%28%29) suggest that the revalidate method is called every time something like size changes and manually calling it with repaint seems to solve problems like these.